# What does "roadway-in-time" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found the phrase 'roadway-in-time' while reading a novel.
The whole sentence was,

> He was two years older than she was, and as she drove along this roadway-in-time, he slowly came into focus once again.

Can you tell me the meaning of it?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful, here; for example, what genre was the novel? (e.g., science-fiction, romance, action/adventure, etc.) A plot summary might help as well. The answer given is certainly possible, but not the only possibility; the additional information requested would help in clarifying the context and perhaps leading to a more definite answer.

Comment: It sounds like a metaphor for the passage of time.

Comment: The word _this_ implies that whatever kind of "roadway" is meant, it has already been mentioned at least once in the prior text, possibly described in very different words.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a 4-dimensional allegory, referring to that she is two years younger, and during the time it takes her to get older (her `roadway-in-time` as it were), her perception of `him` starts making more sense.

Answer (score 0):

roadway-in-time means "old road" which was a useful one in a time.

Comment: An answer will need be justified by a source, or extended explanation as to how the answer was formed.. Otherwise it is opinion. You need to explain how you arrived at your answer for the answer to be taken seriously..